# html - change language using element.lang

Tags: javascript, html, lang

First question on stack, so hurray to me!
I'm trying to develop a new way (apparently, since I've seen no solution to this online, perhaps cos it's not possible) to change the language of HTML written elements using JS and the lang property.

Basically, I have created multiple tags with the lang property in each of them, so that giving the certain lang a display value of -none-, hides it, and a value of -inherit- to show it.
In that way, using the line:

```
a:lang(en),p:lang(en) { display : none }
a:lang(it),p:lang(it) { display : inherit }
```

I can see one language at a time. And that works!

Now, I have created an

```
<a href="" lang="en" id="en"> word </a>
```

tag around the english text, and the same with any other language with their own lang property.
I have tried to use:

```
$("#en").click(function(){
           $('a:lang(en)').css('display', 'inherit');
           $('a:lang(it)').css('display', 'none');
           };
```

Which doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks a bunch,
Shay

Comment: why not make two stylesheets, disable current one and enable another one, when change language.

Comment: I'm just trying to see if there's an easier way to change language. In any case, I wouldn't change a stylesheet just to hide and show a tag, I would create a different page and make that load, which should be easier, no?

Comment: different stylesheets works way faster, and support dynamically added elements after you called the switch. your query would find every occurrence on the page, just imagine there are thousands of elements there, it could be extreemely slow compare to a swap stylesheet operation.

Comment: I'll try that out right away. In case it works, I'll tell you and ask you to write it as an answer, Thanks!

Comment: already gave you an answer, a shorter version. see below

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When load your page come with a `<body class="it">`, and all the `:lang(en)` tags will be hidden.

```
body.en :lang(it) {
  display: none;
}
body.it :lang(en) {
  display: none;
}
```

And when you need to change the language, simply change the `className` of `<body>`.

```
$("#en").click(function(){
  document.body.className = 'en';
};
```

Which is more elegant, and way faster.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gw4eQ/

---

Use `:not` selector to make it work with more languages. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gw4eQ/159/)

```
body:not(.en) :lang(en), 
body:not(.it) :lang(it), 
body:not(.fr) :lang(fr) { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: amazing, thank you so much! works perfectly!
Works even with 4 languages (had to add them in the css):
http://jsfiddle.net/Gw4eQ/9/

Comment: It has been a while since I answered this question. Please don't try with multiple languages, it could give you a hell long list of rules. Try use :not() to shorten the list.

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect:

```
$('a:lang(en)').attr('display', 'inherit');
$('a:lang(it)').attr('display', 'none');
```

There is no attribute "display", instead use:

```
$('a:lang(en)').css('display', 'inherit');
$('a:lang(it)').css('display', 'none');
```

Or simply:

```
$('a:lang(en)').show();
$('a:lang(it)').hide();
```

...but you also have an error here where you didn't wrap your function correctly:

```
$("#en").click(function(){
    $('a:lang(en)').css('display', 'inherit');
    $('a:lang(it)').css('display', 'none');
}; // <---- error
```

Should be: `});`

```
$("#en").click(function(){
    $('a:lang(en)').css('display', 'inherit');
    $('a:lang(it)').css('display', 'none');
}); // <---- fixed
```

Also, I'd use `inline` rather than `inherit`. "inherit" does not mean "default", it means "inherit this property from the parent", which will probably be `block`. `<a>`'s default display is `inline`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Wesley, but I am going witih xiaoyi's answer since it uses only css and no js, as I initially hoped to do (and thought js was necessary).

Comment: Yeah I'd use another approach, just wanted to let you know why your code wasn't working.

Comment: which was exactly why I came here and asked the great hive mind :)

Comment: You should learn to use tools like these so you can debug things on your own: http://getfirebug.com/ https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Have you close 'click' with ) ?

```
$("#en").click(function(){
       $('a:lang(en)').css('display', 'inherit');
       $('a:lang(it)').css('display', 'none');
 });
```