# Change variables on-click in jekyll website?

Tags: jekyll

Is there any way in jekyll by which one can change variables in a website by simply doing a click? For example, my personal webpage is in english, but I want to have a clickable button in the header of the webpage to switch from english to spanish and vice-versa. This is very easy to implement in each of the different sections of the webpage with simple if statements as long as I have a variable that can change with simple clics, e.g.,

```
{% if variable == "en" %}
This is in english
{% else %}
Esto esta en español
{% endif %}
```

I was trying to do this by implementing a variable in the `_config.yml` file (e.g., creating a variable `language: english` and then changing the value of that variable by clicking some button on the header), but I just found out you can't do that; is there any other way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for the input.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the content in english and spanish in the same page, and don't want to visit another page containing the other language, you will have to use javascript to [show/hide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13607315/1165509) the content in english/spanish.

If you can have one post in english and its equivalent in spanish, then adding a variable to the front-matter of each page/post or in the base layout of them to specify its language should work fine. For example, each post will have a `language: es` variable.:

Post in spanish:

```
~~~
title: ...
language: es
~~~~
```

Post in english

```
~~~
title: ...
language: en
~~~~
```

then in your `_layouts/post.html` you can detect the post language:

```
{% if post.language == 'es' %}
Esto esta en español
{% else %}
{# should be 'en' #}
This is in english
{% endif %}
```

There are many different strategies to handle languages in Jekyll websites, for example if you have all your spanish posts in the `/es` folder, then you can detect the language without a variable, or set the variable automatically setting up a *scope* in `_config.yml`

Comment: So there is no way for the user viewing the webpage to select which language he/she wants without javascript? More than in posts, I'm thinking on a, say, "about" part of the webpage. So it only has an index.html but, inside, it has the (text) content on both languages. Depending on what the user has activated (e.g., language = 'en' or 'es'), the idea would be to show the english or spanish content.

Comment: How would the user activate something without javascript? Jekyll is a static site generator.