# How to create a language button function inside mailchimp template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mailchimp

http://torquemag-hhvm.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2015/03/Template-builder.png

Inside the mailchimp template creator, I would like to create a button for switching language.

e.g. France | English

that will change the content e.g. image / text inside the email, is it support and how to create that?

thanks a lot

Comment: Edit: Found a thread that might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606290/html-change-language-using-element-lang

Comment: How would this work INSIDE a template? Only HTML is allowed

Comment: You could use their tags to do so: [Mailchimp Conditional Merge Tags](http://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/use-conditional-merge-tag-blocks)